# Cloud Firestore Rules for location

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to block read in firestore for any records which aren't within 1000m radius of user's current position using [rules.latlng.distance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.LatLng#distance)

[image]

I tried few cases:

1. Rule

```
latlng.value(resource.data.location.latitude, resource.data.location.longitude).distance(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.location) <= 1000;
```

Error

> Property latitude is undefined on object.

2. Rule

```
latlng.value(resource.data.location.getLatitude(), resource.data.location.getLongitude()).distance(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.location) <= 1000;
```

Error

> Function not found error: Name: [getLatitude].

3. Rule

```
latlng.value(resource.data.location.latitude(), resource.data.location.longitude()).distance(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.location) <= 1000;
```

Error

> Function not found error: Name: [latitude].

All of them result in error. The location field is of type GeoPoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a `LatLng` object in security rules. But if you have a GeoPoint in your document already, you can just access that field and it will be a `LatLng` object already.

So as far as I can see, it should be something like this:

```
resource.data.location.distance(
  get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.location
) <= 1000;
```

Comment: I tried that as well, it gives me error `Function not found error: Name: [distance].`